# Repeat the same operation with different datasets

Tags: r, loops, apply

I need to run a code on many data sets (like `df.p2`, `df.p3`) to get charts. Following is the data format that I have.

```
< df.p1
  Date    Sales
Jan 2011  1000
Feb 2011  1120
Mar 2011  1050
.
.
.
```

Like this I have a list of data frames, now I want to run the following code in a loop.

```
ggplot(df.p1, aes(Date,Sales))+
      geom_line()+
     xlab("Month") + ylab("Sales") + 
     ggtitle("Sales-Product1")
```

Comment: `lapply(list.of.dfs, function(x){ggplot(x, ......)})`

Comment: Because it looks like you will need to use different titles for each dataset, you might want to consider a nested list column and a title column in the same tibble dataset (if using `tidyverse` and `purrr` within it)

You could then run `walk2` over a function containing the ggplot2 command, passing the title and data objects as arguments to this.

Comment: @LAP  Thanks it worked well!

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
dates <- as.Date(as.Date("2011-12-30"):as.Date("2012-05-04"), origin="1970-01-01")
Date<-c()
Sales<-c()
    for (i in 1:10) {
    assign(paste0("df.p",i),cbind.data.frame(Date=sample(dates,5),Sales=rnorm(5,1000,100)    )) }
```

Function:

```
lapply(paste0("df.p",1:10), function(x){ggplot(data=eval(parse(text = x)) ,aes(Date,Sales))+geom_line()+xlab("Month")+ylab("Sales")+ggtitle(paste0("Sales-Product for dataset ",x))})
```